# Number uncovering with given equations

Tags: python, performance

I am making a number uncovering app. The program takes in an equation that has numbers hidden as letters, like:

```
abc + d = efg - hi
```

and it will return all the strings like

```
290 + 6 = 347 - 51
290 + 7 = 348 - 51
250 + 6 = 347 - 91
250 + 7 = 348 - 91
290 + 4 = 365 - 71
270 + 4 = 365 - 91
290 + 4 = 375 - 81
280 + 4 = 375 - 91
290 + 7 = 358 - 61
260 + 7 = 358 - 91
290 + 5 = 376 - 81
280 + 5 = 376 - 91
490 + 6 = 527 - 31
...
```

But there can will be duplicated strings. For example, when I input

```
a + b = c
```

the program returns

```
...
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
...
```

**I know that I can put all the strings into set and then iterate through the set again to print out the strings, but I want to know if that is necessary.**

Perhaps in my program there is an unnecessary loop or such that is causing the duplicated strings, which in turns makes its performance slower? If so, I would like to know the proper way of doing it.

Here is my code:

```
from itertools import permutations
from re import findall

ope = '+-*/( ).='
var = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
num = '1234567890'

while True:
    while True:
        whole = input(">>> ") # User inputs equation here
        if any(c not in ope + var + num for c in whole): # Makes sure that all the characters are valid
            print(f'You may only use: {ope}{var}{num}')
            continue
        chars = list({char for char in whole if char in var}) # Extract all the mystery numbers

        if len(chars) > 10: # There are only 10 different digits, so the user may only input 10 different mystery numbers
            print('Enter at most 9 different letters.')
            continue
        while len(chars) < 10: # If there are less that 10 different mystery numbers
            chars.append(None) # add None until the length of the list is 10

        # From here to the break is to check if the syntax works, so a bit processing time is used on the first permutation of chars
        exp = whole
        for i, v in enumerate(chars):
            if v:
                exp = exp.replace(v, str(i))

        if all(int(e[0]) for e in findall('\d+', exp)):
            try:
                eval(exp.replace('=', '=='))
            except SyntaxError:
                print('Invalid Syntax')
                continue
        break # If not continue was hit, that means that the equation is valid

    for p in permutations(chars):
        exp = whole
        for i, v in enumerate(p):
            if v:
                exp = exp.replace(v, str(i))
        if all(int(e[0]) for e in findall('[\d\w]+', exp)): # If all the individual numbers don't begin with 0
            if eval(exp.replace('=', '==')): # If the equation is correct
                print(exp) # Print the equation
```

Comment: Is the problem your own idea, or is it from a challenge website?

Comment: @Reinderien My own problem.

Comment: Long story short, if you want to keep this as a brute-force solution, you should really drop `permutations` and vectorize the thing, potentially with a Numpy `meshgrid` input as I've shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Functions

Split your code into individual smaller functions, doing singular tasks. A few examples would be validating the expression, extracting variables and so on.

### `if __name__` block

For scripts, it is a good practice to put your executable feature inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause.

### Comments

The comments like in:

```
while len(chars) < 10: # If there are less that 10 different mystery numbers
```

are pointless. The condition already explains what you write in 10 words. A more important comment here could've been what the *mystery numbers* are?

This applies to almost all of the comments you have added in your program. Once you split to functions, add docstrings to those functions explaining **what** and maybe **why** the function does. The code should be self-explanatory on the *how*.

### Execution logic

From what I understand of the program, you are:

1. asking user for expression
2. validating if there are any invalid characters
3. extracting variables (and creating a forced list of 10 elements)
4. Not sure about the `findall('\d+', exp)` validation, and later the same thing is being achieved by a different regex pattern
5. check if the expression is mathematically consistent
6. permute all elements from variables list (created above)
7. iterate on all permutations and replace into the expression
8. evaluate expression and print if successful

A lot of the code seems duplicated, for eg. the `exp.replace` calls, the `findall` validation etc. You have to work with 2 nested loops just because there are no helper functions to assist you.

For the permutations themselves, you can obviously permute over a forced set of length 10, or you can just permute over the integers `range(10)` selecting as many elements as there are variables. Since you anyway need those integers (using enumerate), I'd go for this.

As a side note, instead of printing all valid results in the main loop, use a generator and yield valid results.

---

### Example rewrite

```
from typing import Tuple, Set
from itertools import count, permutations

OPERATORS = '+-*/( ).='
VARIABLES = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
NUMERALS = '1234567890'
VALID_CHARACTERS = OPERATORS + VARIABLES + NUMERALS


def is_expression_valid(expression: str) -> bool:
    return all(c in VALID_CHARACTERS for c in expression)


def is_expression_consistent(expression: str, variables: Set[str]) -> bool:
    for index, value in zip(count(1), variables):
        expression = expression.replace(value, str(index))
    try:
        eval(expression.replace("=", "=="))
    except SyntaxError:
        return False
    return True


def extract_variables(expression: str) -> Set[str]:
    variables = {char for char in expression if char in VARIABLES}
    if len(variables) > 10:
        raise ValueError()
    return variables


def get_expression() -> Tuple[str, Set[str]]:
    while True:
        expression = input(">>> ")
        if not is_expression_valid(expression):
            print(f"Invalid characters in the expression. Use only from: {VALID_CHARACTERS}")
            continue
        try:
            variables = extract_variables(expression)
        except ValueError:
            print("Expected at most 9 variable/letters!")
            continue
        if not is_expression_consistent(expression, variables):
            print("Invalid syntax!")
            continue
        break
    return expression, variables


def substitute_expression_format(expression: str) -> str:
    return "".join(r"{}" if c in VARIABLES else c for c in expression)


def valid_results(expression: str, variables: Set[str]) -> str:
    formatted_expression = substitute_expression_format(expression)
    for permute in permutations(range(10), len(variables)):
        variation = formatted_expression.format(*permute)
        if eval(variation.replace("=", "==")):
            yield variation


def main():
    expression, variables = get_expression()
    for result in valid_results(expression, variables):
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Notice in `is_expression_consistent`, I've use `zip` with `itertools.count`, so that the dependency on regex is removed.

Now, the above fails for invalid token check, when the first substitution is \$ 0 \$; which can be resolved by having a `try-except` in the generator:

```
def valid_results(expression: str, variables: Set[str]) -> str:
    formatted_expression = substitute_expression_format(expression)
    for permute in permutations(range(10), len(variables)):
        variation = formatted_expression.format(*permute)
        try:
            if eval(variation.replace("=", "==")):
                yield variation
        except SyntaxError:
            continue
```

You can check the [code on tio.run](https://tio.run/##jVXbTttAEH33V0z9gg0hkNIbkRIppamKREsVAi@osjbJJFlw1u7uGBIQ357urh1fUnPZF8h4Z@bMmTOz8YrmkThar6cyWgCtYi5mwBdxJAmGSRxiAy6QHPuVE0qKolBtLoyjRFADYpSLhBjxSCjHOf/dH/SG54ML6MDO3v7ugQd@s7PjXPUGp72vZ31rZ6PxBKezOb@5DRciiv9KRcnd/XL1sOP8uvypI5zZe633Rx8@fvr85fjQBDg7/Rac/OgNeifDvo1f5NqDIv4ebEI4jqPTAFcBLmOJSmmIwR0L@cQrDG1QJH3Y78JIF9d2QB@JlEgBLAy9MXAB/@WeRhLslyKOX5ttrEnhilDQdsoG3DHJ2ShE1TYkX2vbny0cJg0XE1yay2GCJuMDjz3LvNfySzH81MOcIpHmqPjRlBiHbIyeDdUwGDwb3PetK8lVKYa@5NX4uh23AW6n42ZOuBxjTHCxEsSWfSkjWcTIWPzOQoVlWocywYwsXJJkYwryMmobs2EnDZ3f1dU9judMpt0w/1QaAnyaW3N1PNkQ@kuIwivIgy60DkvIGVcIV4YnW5Pnl/HnblkRM6RSyz0L2Q7PtW3zBn0G/37OQ7QcPNMxLuKEPLfb7YLr51c0ZBHRK1ouicCcWHItk6l7KuxFy4ZmG6UynNAcy@qAS11yJMIVmGlvw@O26J9KaMzR0iYuEsyNFQFtd@qlTvslIqycCubrCnL7yxh1GRNgBItIERznqQ5CJFPgu9fA1vJZO631Q1aCs6FX2SF4pwek3vllQCOJ7LYss9ogmeRUMlLEKSEsw9dzsGBUO0L6b2W1uW7zJuLCk@7jk2snpTImgHpmte2FPWdrDrQxCUm9fbnlQFKwuotBRf1vrMzP92P6/NjVWH6JPMnEDL3WoV6S1VkvNdEaKU1ch6eZ5d3NkvjPa11TaHdmHrJuZVZdzFlxDCcFju1BqN2rFfmkzVgw3cssfK1udIHbaypnMO2hIfC5ntaPQCr/9LZRhaYgCARbYBBApwNuEBhYQeCmLilGZ73Wr79@pCdmKUxnsA9z/g8).

---

### EDIT

For fixing the issue mentioned in comments (about repeated letters):

```
def substitute_expression_format(expression: str) -> str:
    return "".join(f"{{{c}}}" if c in VARIABLES else c for c in expression)


def valid_results(expression: str, variables: Set[str]) -> str:
    formatted_expression = substitute_expression_format(expression)
    for permute in permutations(range(10), len(variables)):
        variation = formatted_expression.format(**dict(zip(variables, permute)))
        try:
            if eval(variation.replace("=", "==")):
                yield variation
        except SyntaxError:
            continue
```

Updated example [on tio.run](https://tio.run/##jVXbbtpAEH33V0z9EjshJDS9BQkkmlI1UtpUhOQlqqzFDLCJWbu74wSC@Ha6uwbbUOeyL@DxzsyZM3PGyZwmsThZrUYyngLNEy7GwKdJLAn6aRJhDa6QHPuWE0qK40htLoRxKqgGCcppSox4LJTjXP7u9jr9y94VtGDv4HD/yAO/3tpzbjq9887Xi661s0E4xNF4wu/uo6mIk79SUfrwOJs/7Tm/rn/qCBf2XuP9yYePnz5/OT02AS7OvwVnPzq9zlm/a@MXuQ6giH8AmxCO4@g0wFWAs0SiUhpi8MAiPvQKQxMUSR8O2zDQxTUd0EcipVIAiyIvBC7gv9yjWIJ9U8TxK7OFmhSuCAXtpqzBA5OcDSJUTUPyrbb92cFh0nAxxJm5HKVoMj7xxLPMew2/FMPPPMwpEmmOioe6xCRiIXo2VM1g8Gxw37euJOelGPqSV@HrttwauK2Wu3bCWYgJwdVcEJt1pYxlEWPN4ncWKSzT2pcprsnCGUkWUpCXUdmYDTtZ6Pyurm4RTpjMumH@bDUE@Ci35tOxtCH0mwiFV5AHbWgcl5AzrhBuDE@2Js8v48/d1kWMkUot9yxkK55b2@YN@jX8xwmP0HLwTMe4SFLy3Ha7Da6fX9GQRUyvzHJpCMxJJNdjMnLPhb1o2dBso1SGE5pgeTrgWpcci2gORu1NWOwO/bKExhw92sRFirlxa4B2O/VSp/0SEXacCuarCnK7swR1GUNgBNNYEZzmqY4iJFPgu9fAVvJZqdZqkZXgbOhVVgTvtECqnV8GNJDI7stjVhlkPXIqHSjilBKW4WsdTBlVSkj/bq02163fxVzo4VgsFuFyuXStXLa0AqiFq20vLDtbeKCNaUTq7RsuR5Mh1q0MtiTwxvL8fElm3yC7H8ufI08yMUavcaw35bbgS520RsoSV@Gpr/Pu7w95SJ7Zv3mczdcPfd9/XgeaWbtP80xV63TbxZw5x2hYwNsVSeXO3RqtrEdTpvu8Dl85U7ru3RWWE5u11vD6XKur5ZFJI7tthkVTEASCTTEIoNUCNwgMrCBwM5cMo7NaTRiDQxhoSBr6Pw).

Comment: The `findall('\d+', exp)` if statement is to make sure none of the integers begin with `0`, because abc cannot be equal to `089`, as `089` is the equivalent of just `89`.

Comment: You code returns an error when we use the same letter more than once. For example: `haa - b = def`

Comment: @user229550 updated for the same in my post.

Comment: Naive `eval` is quite dangerous. You're going to want to eliminate all of the built-ins, as I've shown in my solution.

Comment: @Reinderien But doesn't the conditions filter out the danger? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't trust it. Disabling built-ins is an easy step, and it's worth the (very minimal) cost if it means reducing attack surface area.

Comment: Also this throws for some inputs including `abc - cab = ab`

Comment: @Reinderien The whole point of the OP's problem was that for letters `x` and `y`, they should never have the same values. So, in your example \$ abc - cab = ab \$, the valid answers require either \$ a = b = c \$ or \$ a = b \$.

Comment: Fine - so output an error message to that effect, instead of `IndexError: Replacement index 3 out of range for positional args tuple`.

Comment: @Reinderien I think you're using the code from pre-edit.

Comment: I'm sorry; my mistake. I propose that you keep your edit-message but simply replace the old code. Anyway, with the new code, it silently fails, which is only marginally better - a message saying that there were no valid solutions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, but given the broad range of expression operators permitted I believe it's infeasible to arrive at an exact solution.

Your approach is definitely broken in at least one category of cases, and I think an integer-math general solution is either difficult or maybe impossible.

Take for instance

```
>>> 35 / (7/3)
14.999999999999998
>>> 35 / (7/3) == 15
False
>>>
```

You're expecting that floating-point comparison is going to do what you want, but there are many circumstances where it won't.

A quick, approximate fix is to

- avoid doing direct comparison
- evaluate the left and right sides separately
- set some small epsilon value like `1e-12` under which any errors are considered equal.

A more careful brute-force approach is to vectorize your parameter space and use Numpy. Given that every added variable introduces another factor of 10 this will need to be limited, and might require segmentation (which I have not done) - but it stands a very good chance of running faster than your original.

I'm also going to propose that you be more careful with `eval`, and don't parse anything yourself. Tell the Python AST to run parsing, and do selective node replacement e.g. from `ab` to `10*a + 1*b`. The following code does this, and offers a more secure and performant solution.

```
import ast
import numpy as np
from typing import Callable, Mapping, Tuple, Sequence, List


Args = Mapping[str, int]
Callback = Callable[[Args], float]
NO_BUILTINS = {'__builtins__': {}}
MAX_VARS = 5


class ExprSyntaxError(SyntaxError):
    pass


class DigitTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.names = set()

    def visit_Name(self, node: ast.Name) -> ast.AST:
        self.names.update(node.id)

        digits = len(node.id)
        if digits == 1:
            return node

        digit_expr = '+'.join(
            f'{10**(digits - i)}*{letter}'
            for i, letter in enumerate(node.id, 1)
        )
        return ast.parse(digit_expr, mode='eval').body


def make_cb(side: ast.AST) -> Callback:
    code = compile(
        ast.Expression(side),
        filename='<stdin>',
        mode='eval',
        dont_inherit=True,
    )

    def execute(args: Args) -> float:
        return eval(code, NO_BUILTINS, args)
    return execute


def parse(expr: str) -> Tuple[
    List[str],
    Callback,
    Callback,
]:
    tree = ast.parse(expr, mode='eval')
    trans = DigitTransformer()
    compare = trans.visit(tree).body
    if not (
        isinstance(compare, ast.Compare) and
        isinstance(compare.ops[0], ast.Eq)
    ):
        raise ExprSyntaxError('Only == is supported')

    lhs, (rhs,) = compare.left, compare.comparators
    return sorted(trans.names), make_cb(lhs), make_cb(rhs)


def solve(letters: Sequence[str], lhs_fun: Callback, rhs_fun: Callback) -> np.array:
    n = len(letters)

    ten_by_n = np.repeat(
        np.arange(10)[np.newaxis, ...],
        n, axis=0
    )
    grid = np.array(
        np.meshgrid(*ten_by_n)
    ).T.reshape(-1, n)
    params = dict(zip(letters, grid.T))

    error = np.abs(lhs_fun(params) - rhs_fun(params))
    return grid[error < 1e-12, :]


def capture() -> Tuple[
    List[str],
    Callback,
    Callback,
]:
    while True:
        try:
            letters, lhs, rhs = parse(
                input('Expression: ')
            )
            if len(letters) <= MAX_VARS:
                return letters, lhs, rhs
            print(f'{len(letters)} variables exceeds the maximum of {MAX_VARS}.')
        except SyntaxError:
            pass


def main():
    while True:
        letters, lhs, rhs = capture()
        sorted_letters = sorted(letters)
        solutions = solve(sorted_letters, lhs, rhs)

        print(f'{len(solutions)} solutions', end='')
        if len(solutions):
            print(':')
            print(', '.join(sorted_letters))
            print(solutions)
        else:
            print()
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example output:

```
Expression: abc - cab == ab
2 solutions:
a, b, c
[[0 0 0]
 [9 9 8]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Just so you know, every letter must have a different value, and numbers such as `abc` cannot be `056`, because `056` will be counted as only 2 digits.

Comment: @Chocolate Do you mean that _every letter must have a different value_, and/or _every letter must appear at most once in the input_? Your problem description does not mention either constraint.

Comment: The comment in my code `# There are only 10 different digits, so the user may only input 10 different mystery numbers`; every letter must have a different value, so the user can input a maximum of 10 different letters. But reusing the same letter wouldn't count as another different letter.

Comment: This part of the code `if all(int(e[0]) for e in findall('\d+', exp)):` ensures that no integer begins with 0.

Comment: I see; so letters needn't be unique, but values must be. Thanks for the clarification.